# Supabase Self-Hosted Keycloak Integration

Tags: authentication, oauth, keycloak, supabase

I have been trying for quite some time to get a self hosted instance to communicate with a self hosted instance of keycloak.
I get the following error -

> Unable+to+exchange+external+code:+6c4407d3-17ca-44c9-bf9c-c659a0f52e40.51dee7bb-fedb-4799-acd3-d9cfba80f36e.a2f16c7a-e0eb-46bd-9f69-9deb84df9113

Can someone provide the necessary docker-compose configuration required plus the required configuration for the keycloak oauth client, specifically the redirect uris. Assume all docker containers will be run from the same machine using localhost.

I am using one of the supabase nextjs examples to test the auth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a docker compose [example](https://medium.com/@kaloyanmanev/bitnami-keycloack-inside-docker-compose-import-realm-on-startup-3627a7da7f39) you can use to run keycloak locally:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: bitnami/keycloak
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/keycloak/realms:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/data/import
```

you should add a postgresql to it...

Now if you are running supabase and keycloak locally using docker, you are going to run into issues with redirection. e.g: when supabase docker will try to call the token endpoint it won't work if you use localhost ... Therefore, you should use another address, for example your local network IP.

On the Supabase side, you can use the CLI to initialize the project which will create a `config.toml` file, make sure to configure your `config.toml`. Here's a couple points:

```ini
[auth]
enabled = true
# The base URL of your website. Used as an allow-list for redirects and for constructing URLs used
# in emails.
site_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
# A list of *exact* URLs that auth providers are permitted to redirect to post authentication.
additional_redirect_urls = ["**"]

...

[auth.external.keycloak]
enabled = true
client_id = "supabase"
# DO NOT commit your OAuth provider secret to git. Use environment variable substitution instead:
secret = "env(SUPABASE_AUTH_EXTERNAL_KEYCLOAK_SECRET)"

# Overrides the default auth redirectUrl.
# Default url is: http://127.0.0.1:54321/auth/v1/callback
redirect_uri = ""
# Overrides the default auth provider URL. Used to support self-hosted gitlab, single-tenant Azure,
# or any other third-party OIDC providers.
url = "http://YOUR_KEYCLOAK_HOST:YOUR_KEYCLOAK_PORT/realms/{your_realm}"
```

hope this helps.